# Count Number of Clicks on a link (Without onclick)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, onclick, hyperlink

I have links such as these

```
"""<a href="http://xyz.com/pz/jjjjj/"><img src="http://xyzsho/mbd.com/42/1319/11110/" alt="" border="0"></a>""""
```

stored in a mysql database. The user copies these links from some other website and uploads it to the database. These links are now to be displayed on our site. How can I count and store the number of clicks on each link. Here i am unable to use onclick.

I am using PHP and MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: why can't you use onClick. your question is a little vague, can you provide more detail?

Comment: Why can't you use onclick? Can you use other javascript? What's the setup you have regarding this? Need abit more information

Comment: Can you use any event handlers? It'll be a little tough, otherwise, unless you modify the links.

Comment: the links that a user copies are in the following format """<a href=""><img src=""></a>""" - so u see, they are already enclosed in <a> tags

Comment: What you want to achieve is called tracking and this is illegal

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite the URL to first hit some other server you can use for statistics gathering, and then redirect the user to their initial URL.

This is the sort of thing used by Twitter or Facebook any time you click one of their off-site links.

Essentially, you're writing a URL shortener.